# How do I switch SSL providers in MUP

Tags: meteor, mup

In order to use Letsencrypt SSL in MUP I just use add a proxy in the config file:

```
proxy: {
domains: 'mydomain.com,www.mudomain.com',
ssl: {
  // Enable let's encrypt to create free certificates.
  // The email is used by Let's Encrypt to notify you when the
  // certificates are close to expiring.
  letsEncryptEmail: 'user@candidsky.com'
  // forceSSL: true
}
```

},

The documentation is here

http://meteor-up.com/docs.html#ssl-support

But I can't find anything on how to use a custom SSL, I need to use comodo SSL.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom SSL" ?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I set up an SSL with comodoSSL, they provided me with a pem and key after authorisation. I need to use comodo SSL instead of letsencrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it

```
app: {
  ...
  ssl: {
    crt: './bundle.crt', // this is a bundle of certificates
    key: './private.key', // this is the private key of the certificate
    port: 443 // 443 is the default value and it's the standard HTTPS port
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that you also can set pem key in the key field.
http://meteor-up.com/docs.html#ssl-support

Comment: I've tried this already but it still uses Letsencrypt as the Issue name.

It basically creates a docker image with Letsencrypt forcing a SSL with them. Which gets denied on the browser. The following is the docker image that gets created with a mup setup:

43534c01c43d jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion "/bin/bash /app/entr…" mup-nginx-proxy-letsencrypt

Comment: try to do mup setup and then mup reconfig